# Probability: Theory and Examples Version 5a Durrett Exercises 4.8.5

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes

> 4.8.5. Variance of the time of gambler's ruin. Let $\xi_{1}, \xi_{2}, \ldots$ be independent with $P\left(\xi_{i}=1\right)=p$ and
> $P\left(\xi_{i}=-1\right)=q=1-p$ where $p<1 / 2 .$ Let
> $S_{n}=S_{0}+\xi_{1}+\cdots+\xi_{n}$and let $V_{0}=\min \left\{n \geq
> > 0: S_{n}=0\right\}$. Theorem 4.8 .9 tells us that $E_{x} V_{0}=x /(1-2
> > p)$ The aim of this problem is to compute the variance of $V_{0} .$ If
> we let $Y_{i}=\xi_{i}-(p-q)$ and note that $E Y_{i}=0$
> and$$\operatorname{var}\left(Y_{i}\right)=\operatorname{var}\left(X_{i}\right)=E
> > X_{i} u^{2}-\left(E X_{i}\right)^{2}$$then it follows that
> $\left(S_{n}-(p-q) n\right)^{2}-n\left(1-(p-q)^{2}\right)$ is a
> martingale. (a) Use this to conclude that when $S_{0}=x$ the variance
> of $V_{0}$ is$$x \cdot \frac{1-(p-q)^{2}}{(q-p)^{3}}$$

I know that there are some answers to this question on the Internet, but what I am curious about is not his answer, but how this formula is derived:
$\left(S_{n}-(p-q) n\right)^{2}-n\left(1-(p-q)^{2}\right)$. I would be grateful if anyone could help me.

Answer (score 0):

Let $ \{ \zeta_i \} $ be a sequence of iid random variables with $ \mathbb{E} \zeta = 0 $ and $ \mathbb{E} \zeta^2 = \sigma^2 < \infty $. If we let $ T_n = \zeta_1 + \cdots + \zeta_n $, then $ 
T_n^2 - n\sigma^2 $ is a martingale. (See Example 4.2.2.) Now you should be able to show that this is actually a uniformly integrable martingale.

The formula you've mentioned can exactly be derived from this when we centralize $ \xi $'s.